# find out how a person is feeling?

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, emotion

How might I create a C# program to decide how, say, sad a person is? Do you think it might work just to pick out "depressed" words, or would that not go far enough? I could use a neural network if needed.

UPDATE: Assuming that we know the prompt that the user is referring to, and that we know how that prompt should be responded to. We also have other sentences that they have marked as "happy", "sad" etc. Yes, they are in front of a webcam with a mic. Sorry if the question is too vague.

Comment: You question is not quite clear. Can you give more details? What are the inputs? what are the possible outputs (sad, happy, angry...)? What technology/plateform?...

Comment: There is so much missing from this question, it could be considered "not a real question".  How are you getting your information?  Can you use biometrics?  How would you define whether someone is sad?  If you had access to all their social network personas you may get an idea, but that would mean you first have to know what is normal for them.  If you don't know what is normal, then you would have no idea when they are other than happy, for example.

Comment: How can the program examine the user?  Are they in front of a webcam? Can you record their voice and analyse it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While your question is terribly vague, it sounds like you are looking for sentiment analysis.

A good starting point is the Wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis